# android how to check in java before saving record the string value already exist in mysql data base

Tags: java, php

I have 6 string value but I want to check one string for the record, the value before the record in MySQL database.

I have a dot, where I want to check in java is PHP.

```
$billno = $_POST["billno"];
$date = $_POST["date"];
$customer_name = $_POST["customer_name"];
$customer_number = $_POST["customer_number"];
$remark = $_POST["remark"];
$amount = $_POST["amount"];
```

I want to insert data and also want to check customer_number already exist.

Answer (score 1):

Set the customer number column to unique in Mysql DB. It will give an error in response while trying to insert duplicate customer number into db.